# Run a perticular debug on press of android studio's PLAY

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-productflavors

On pressing Play button of studio if you see the logs of gradle using below command:

```
gradlew tasks --stacktrace –info
```

It's showing that it is running debug tasks of all flavors, though I have selected variant as a flavor.

Is it possible to identify which flavor is selected in build variant?

Answer (score 1):

It means you have to add --debug in Settings>Build,Execution,Deployment>Compiler. So that you can view clear logs or errors.